# Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDecimal128' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'

Tags: c#, mongodb, swagger

I had an issue with sorting my collection by a decimal value that I've inserted into a MongoDB database with the `decimal` type.

Shortly after I've realized that the MongoDB driver converted the value wrong; in the database the value gets falsely converted into a `string` and that's why the sorting doesn't work.

So, I've tried using the `BsonDecimal128` type to insert it into the database. That works perfectly in the database and shows as a Decimal128! The sorting also worked correctly when testing it out in MongoDBCompass.

But, once I tried to connect to the Swagger UI to test the shell queries, it freezes and there's a browser popup saying that the page is slowing down my browser. That hasn't happened before.
[image: Image of the browser error]

When I try it via the URL I get the error message `InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDecimal128' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'.`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found a workaround. I converted the calculated decimal value into a `double` and it seems to do the trick:

```cs
Value = Convert.ToDouble(value)
```

It's better to avoid `decimal` as long as `double` works too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).